# C# Naudio, play entirely and then loop at position X to the end and return to X

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm working on a method where the idea is, first play the sound from start to end, and loop the sound from the sample X to the end and return to that X and play it indefinitely until the user clicks the stop button.

For this I've been using this tutorial:
http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/10/looped-playback-in-net-with-naudio.html

I've changed a bit the "buttonStartStop_Click" method, my method is:

```
internal void PlayAudioLoopOffset(WaveOut AudioPlayer, byte[] PCMData, int Frequency, int Pitch, int Bits, int Channels, int Pan, int loopPosition)
{
    if (WaveOut.DeviceCount > 0)
    {
        if (AudioPlayer.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped)
        {
            AudioSample = new MemoryStream(PCMData);
            using (LoopStream loop = new LoopStream(new RawSourceWaveStream(AudioSample, new WaveFormat(Frequency + Pitch, Bits, Channels))))
            {
                loop.Position = loopPosition;
                VolumeSampleProvider volumeProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(loop.ToSampleProvider());
                PanningSampleProvider panProvider = new PanningSampleProvider(volumeProvider)
                {
                    Pan = (Pan / 100)
                };
                AudioPlayer.DeviceNumber = GlobalPreferences.DefaultAudioDevice;
                AudioPlayer.Volume = 1;
                AudioPlayer.Init(panProvider);
                AudioPlayer.Play();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Show Error
        MessageBox.Show(GenericFunctions.resourcesManager.GetString("NoAudioDevices"), "EuroSound", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        //Stop and dispose
        StopAudio(AudioPlayer);
    }
}
```

What's the problem I'm having?

When I click play, the sound starts on the X position instead of starting from the start, and then loops the sound from the start to the end indefinitely instead of from the sample X.

Represented with an image, the idea is to do this:
[image]

Thanks to @Hazrelle now I'm a bit closer, but there's another problem, there's a bit of delay when the first audio stops and the second one starts to play, here's a recording: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nG7OFv2QaA1FIaNM27UKWxrKw6yIco6d/view?usp=sharing

This is the new code I'm using:

```
internal void PlayAudioLoopPoint(WaveOut AudioPlayer, uint LoopPos, decimal Volume, byte[] PCMData, int Frequency, int Pitch, int Bits, int Channels, decimal AudioPan)
{
    MemoryStream AudioSample = new MemoryStream(PCMData);
    WaveFormat soundWavFormat = new WaveFormat(CalculateValidRate(Frequency, Pitch), Bits, Channels);
    RawSourceWaveStream FullStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(AudioSample, soundWavFormat);
    AudioPlayer.Init(FullStream);
    AudioPlayer.Play();
    AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped += (se, ev) => audioPlayer_PlaybackStopped(AudioPlayer, PCMData, AudioSample, soundWavFormat, (int)LoopPos);
}

private void audioPlayer_PlaybackStopped(WaveOut AudioPlayer, byte[] PCMData, MemoryStream AudioSample, WaveFormat soundWavFormat, int LoopPos)
{
    MemoryStream SubsetStream = new MemoryStream(PCMData, LoopPos, (int)AudioSample.Length - LoopPos);
    LoopStream LoopStream = new LoopStream(new RawSourceWaveStream(SubsetStream, soundWavFormat));
    AudioPlayer.Init(LoopStream);
    AudioPlayer.Play();
}
```

Comment: This is what you coded.
You load the "full sample" into a `MemoryStream`. Then you include this 'full sample' into a `LoopStream` setting the start position to X.
So when you play this `LoopStream` it starts at X to the end and then loop from position 0 to end.
1. Load the `MemoryStream`` and play it with `AudioPlayer.Play();`
2. Create a new `MemoryStream` of the original `MemoryStream` starting from position X to end.
3. Create the `LoopStream` with the subset `MemoryStream`
4. Play the `LoopStream` with `AudioPlayer.Play();`

Comment: @Hazrelle I see, thank you very much for your response, will try to do it, I don't have too much experience, I'm still learning programming. Could you show me how this code would look?

Comment: Pretty exactly the same than you did. But you have to separate steps and construct a `new RawSourceWaveStream(Stream ...)`. Clearly I don't know the objects you use, nor I know music programming. But the errors are not really in your code, it is just how you sequence usage of the streams. See a stream a a sequence of byte that represent the music you play. A stream has a position 0 and a Length, so that when position equals Length - 1 the stream has reached the end. What is a LoopStream ? It is a stream that when then position equals Length - 1, it does reset position to 0.

Comment: @Hazrelle, I've been trying it, but for some unknown reason all sounds plays at the same time, the loop and the sound from the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally find a solution implementing a class called "loop stream":
https://markheath.net/post/looped-playback-in-net-with-naudio

After implementing it, I've added a new property for the start position, the method that creates the IWaveProvider looks like this:

```
internal IWaveProvider CreateMonoLoopWav(int startPos, int _startLoop, bool flags, byte[] _pcmData, int _frequency, float _pitch, float _pan, float _volume)
{
    RawSourceWaveStream provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(new MemoryStream(_pcmData), new WaveFormat(SemitonesToFreq(_frequency, _pitch), 16, 1));
    LoopStream loop = new LoopStream(provider, _startLoop) { EnableLooping = flags, Position = startPos };
    PanningSampleProvider panProvider = new PanningSampleProvider(loop.ToSampleProvider()) { Pan = _pan };
    VolumeSampleProvider volumeProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(panProvider) { Volume = _volume };

    return volumeProvider.ToWaveProvider();
}
```

And this is my version of the class loop stream:

```
public class LoopStream : WaveStream
{
    private readonly int _start;
    private readonly WaveStream sourceStream;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Loop stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceStream">The stream to read from. Note: the Read method of this stream should return 0 when it reaches the end
    /// or else we will not loop to the start again.</param>
    public LoopStream(WaveStream sourceStream, long start)
    {
        this.sourceStream = sourceStream;
        this.EnableLooping = true;
        _start = (int)(start & -2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this to turn looping on or off
    /// </summary>
    public bool EnableLooping { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return source stream's wave format
    /// </summary>
    public override WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get { return sourceStream.WaveFormat; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoopStream simply returns
    /// </summary>
    public override long Length
    {
        get { return sourceStream.Length; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoopStream simply passes on positioning to source stream
    /// </summary>
    public override long Position
    {
        get { return sourceStream.Position; }
        set { sourceStream.Position = value; }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int totalBytesRead = 0;

        while (totalBytesRead < count)
        {
            int bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, offset + totalBytesRead, count - totalBytesRead);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                if (sourceStream.Position == 0 || !EnableLooping)
                {
                    // something wrong with the source stream
                    break;
                }
                // loop
                sourceStream.Position = _start;
            }
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        }
        return totalBytesRead;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With something like that ?
But you may have to create a new AudioPlayer for each stream.
I don't have all the types of your objects. I guess AudioPlayer is a SimplePlaybackPanel from NAudio. But I'm not sure. Internally it does use a IWavePlayer implementation that is a WaveOut object.
Code from [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/fb35ce8367f30b8bc5ea84e7d2529e172cf4c381/NAudioDemo/SimplePlaybackDemo/SimplePlaybackPanel.cs) is inspiring.
Maybe you have to use `AudioPlayer.Stop()` to stop the first sound.

```
var AudioSample = new MemoryStream(PCMData);
var FullStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(AudioSample, new WaveFormat(Frequency + Pitch, Bits, Channels));
AudioPlayer.Init(FullStream);
AudioPlayer.Play();

var SubsetStream = new MemoryStream(AudioSample.GetBuffer(), position, AudioSample.Length - position);

var LoopStream = new LoopStream(SubsetStream);
AudioPlayer.Init(LoopStream);
AudioPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: Yeah, for some reason all AudioPlayer starts at the same time, I had to adapt a bit the code because I get an error "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed"

Comment: I also discovered that there's an event called "PlaybackStopped", I've adapted a bit the code, but there's another problem. I've added a link in the edit, there's a bit of delay, not sure how can I fix this.

Comment: Yes because computing the Stream take some time. LoopStream and FullStream may be 'prepared' so that you don't have to wait computations. Same issue may occur with 2 AudioPlayer. Because when you Stop() the first audio player, the internal buffer is still filled and there is a 100ms delay for the stop to occur. If you start the second audio player before stopping the first, there may be 100ms where both buffers are played.

Comment: The `WaveOut` object support a `DesiredLatency` [property](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/fb35ce8367f30b8bc5ea84e7d2529e172cf4c381/NAudioWpfDemo/AudioPlaybackDemo/AudioPlayback.cs#L59). Ideally you should set it to 0 in this case. So that Play() and Stop() wouldn't suffer of any overlapping.

Comment: I've put it before AudioPlayer.Play(), but the loop part is muted.

Comment: There should be 2 AudioPlayer objects. But if AudioPlayer is a `SimplePlaybackPanel` this is just an UI component. This doesn't help because the UI responsible load the file ...
In fact you should have:
- PlayerUI `SimplePlaybackPanel`
- 2 `WaveOut` objects. You call `WaveOut.Init()` on both with the FullStream and the LoopStream respectively and a `DesiredLatency` set to 0 `var wo = new WaveOut() { DesiredLatency = 0};`
- Then in your `PlayAudioLoopPoint` you play the first WaveOut object, you register the event `PlaybackStopped`, in the event call the second `WaveOut.Play()` object.

Comment: I've tried it today but does not work, it happens the same, there's a delay before the loop starts :(

Comment: I probably cannot help more without access to a complete demo. And I'm not a sound specialist :)

Comment: You're not providing enough info.